# R how to do this stata code: by panel_key (t), sort: keep if _N == 2?

Tags: r, stata

I have a df called "combined" where pre and post experimental observations are stored. The observations are stacked on each other like this:

```
panel_key <- c(123, 123, 456, 456, 789, 789, 147, 147, 258)
t <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)
treatment<- c(0,0,1,1,2,2,1,2,1)
dependantvar <- c(1,2,2,1,3,4,1,2,4)
df <- data.frame(panel_key, t, treatment, dependantvar)
```

`t` indicates pre (0) and post (1) and `panel_key` indexes the individuals. Some individuals have the same `panel_key` in the pre treatment. The objective here is to match `panel_key` only if they are the same at `t`=0 and `t`=1. Another way to think about this is that I want to drop all rows at `t`=0 that don't have matching panel_key at `t`=1.

Comment: The Stata code `by panel_key (t), sort: keep if _N == 2` keeps panels with precisely two observations (rows in the dataset). The code says nothing about any values of any variable other than `panel_key`. In particular if there were values of `t` other than 0 or 1 or if `t` were 0 or 1 in both observations those pairs of observations aren't disqualified. Perhaps that won't bite with the OP's dataset but as the question is posed in terms of translating Stata code the detail is important. I think it would be easier just to ask directly what you want to do in R. (I am very positive about Stata.)

Comment: Otherwise put Stata code for the problem stated could be `bysort panel_key (t) : keep if _N == 2 & t[1] == 0 & t[2] == 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple tidyverse solution

```
library(tidyverse)

panel_key <- c(123, 123, 456, 456, 789, 789, 147, 147, 258)
t <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)
treatment<- c(0,0,1,1,2,2,1,2,1)
dependantvar <- c(1,2,2,1,3,4,1,2,4)
df <- data.frame(panel_key, t, treatment, dependantvar)


detect_0_1 <- function(vector) {
  all(c(0,1) %in% vector)
}

df %>% 
  group_by(panel_key) %>% 
  filter(detect_0_1(t))
```